# How to convert a list of user ids to the user tags with a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a command which sets notes for the mentioned user with the replit database and I am now working on a list command but I have saved the notes keys as the users id and when I am listing them its showing the ids but I want it to shows their tags is their any way to do this

My code:
setnote:

```
if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Staff')) return;
  const user = message.mentions.members.first()
  if(!user) return message.lineReply("Mention someone to set notes");
  const amount = parseInt(message.content.split('>')[1].toLowerCase().replace('k', '000').replace('m', '000000').replace('b', '000000000'))
  if(isNaN(amount)) return message.lineReply("Please provide a valid number!");
db.get("donation" + user.id).then(newdonated => {
  if(!newdonated) newdonated = 0;
  const donated = parseInt(newdonated)
  const value = donated + amount;
  db.set(user.id, value)
  const desc = `**${user.user.tag}** has now donated **${value.toLocaleString()}** previously had donated **${donated.toLocaleString()}**`;
  let sn = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(user.user.tag, user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true}))
  .setFooter("Bot made by Sɱαɾƚx Gαɱιɳɠ YT")
  .setColor("ORANGE")
  .setDescription(desc)
  .setTitle("Donation added!")
  .setDescription(`**${user.user.tag}** has now donated **${value.toLocaleString()}** previously had donated **${donated.toLocaleString()}**`)
  message.lineReplyNoMention(sn)
```

list code:

```
db.list().then(members => {
    members.forEach(member => {
    const user = bot.users.cache.get(member);
    const people = user.user.tag;
    message.lineReply(people)
    })
  });
```

Comment: `user.tag` is ok cause `bot.users.cache.get(member)` return user object

Comment: yes but I think the problem is with the list .-.

Comment: upvote for other to know this helpful anyway

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what the `members` return but if you want a list of user tags  try this:

````
const listOfTags = message.guild.members.cache.map((m) => m.user.tag); // This returns an array of user tags```
````